# How to configure Webpack & Babel to fail on undeclared variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am using webpack with Babel to build my React application.

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['env', 'react']
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
```

I have recently been using `env` (formerly `es2015`), so part of my code has some undeclared variables. I would like to configure webpack to fail at build rather than having a buggy js, which at execution which throws me error like :

```
assignment to undeclared variable fooBar
```

Comment: @Aaqib That plugin is deprecated, better to use ESLint if you need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if Babel can do that, but [Eslint](https://eslint.org/) sure can! Simply setup your Eslint config file; as well, implement Eslint into your webpack config using [Eslint Webpack Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-eslint-plugin) so it can fail on building. Feel free to let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: It was a bit cumbersome to configure, but I got it all set. Thanks!